# I am trying to embed global session variables with url using iframe

Tags: php, session, iframe, drupal

I am trying to embed session variables to url that are set by another module in drupal 7.When i try to make an iframe the iframe works but my session variables are not embedded with url.

Any help will be much appreciated.i also checked sessions using devel modules session viewer they are shown there.
Here is the code that i am using in the iframe content type.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com?"$_SESSION['name']""></iframe>
```

Comment: Try this :  <iframe src=http://www.w3schools.com?<?=$_SESSION['name']?>></iframe>

Comment: still not working......thanks for the help

Comment: how you write php code in druple for fountend ?

Comment: i used the iframe module and set the values there.....if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){
      $path = str_replace("__name__",$_SESSION['name'] , $path);

Comment: why you doing extra efforts for this. try this : 1.) <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com?{$_SESSION['name']}"></iframe>   2.)  echo "<iframe src=http://www.w3schools.com?$_SESSION['name']></iframe>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actully im not aware about drupal but i think this will work

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com?sname='"<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"'"></iframe>
```

please try this

Comment: thanks mate i got the solution but your advice was big help

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['name'] shoud be 
You need to add php code tag for php code.
Always use  for dyanmic codde

Answer (score 0):

i am not drupal developer but in this iframe php syntax is not proper. concatenation is missing .

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com?"<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>""></iframe>
```

please try this.

Comment: sorry but this did not help either